# Objective C: UISlider (Curve)

Tags: objective-c, ios, uislider

Is it possible to have a curve UISlider or is it just Horizontal and Vertical?

I've tried replacing the slider track with a curve image (though i already know hat it will not work because it is just a background), not working.

Is there a way that i could do that?

Comment: What exactly do you mean by curve? A quadratic curve? Bezier curve? Circular curve?

Comment: a circular curve maybe, something like "C"

Comment: Are you trying to create a circular slider (like the volume control on an old stereo)?

Answer (score 2):

Take a look at custom controls (both of them are under MIT license):

1. MHRotaryKnob

   [Cocoacontrols](http://cocoacontrols.com/platforms/ios/controls/mhrotaryknob)

   [Github](https://github.com/hollance/MHRotaryKnob)
2. DCKnob

   [Cocoacontrols](http://cocoacontrols.com/platforms/ios/controls/dcknob)

   [Github](https://github.com/domesticcatsoftware/DCControls)

Answer (score 2):

I wrote this sample app to show how to use a Curve UIBezierPath and move an object through it 
you can take a look at :

- [Curvy UISlider](https://github.com/milianoo/CurvySlider)

I will try to update it.

Answer (score 0):

No you can't do this with the UISlider, only in a straight line. You can rotate the whole slider to a degree you like with the [transform](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/uikit/reference/uiview_class/UIView/UIView.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40006816-CH3-SW4) property and use a function like [CGAffineTransformMakeRotation](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/graphicsimaging/Reference/CGAffineTransform/Reference/reference.html#//apple_ref/c/func/CGAffineTransformRotate). An example: [How to use CGAffineTransformMakeRotation?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5725099/how-to-use-cgaffinetransformmakerotation).

Answer (score 0):

You can also check out [BezierSlider](https://github.com/jgafni/BezierSlider) which allows you to customize the path and the selector.