# Animation for clicking on imageview, cool small blowup

Tags: ios, xcode

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to use CGAffineTransformMakeRotation?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5725099/how-to-use-cgaffinetransformmakerotation)

I have an imageview that acts like a button, I am looking for a way to show the user that he clicked on it, I came up with this code that will rotate it a bit :

```
 float angle =  60.0;
[UIView animateWithDuration:0.5f animations:^{
    customimageView.transform = CGAffineTransformMakeRotation(angle);
}];
```

but its not doing the behavior I am looking fpr.
Anyone know how can I make the imagekinda zoom in ( or enlarge/ blowup ) to maybe 1.5 its size on its click? what kind of animation is relevant here?
feel free to share behaviors you guys thought was cool in this situation.

Thanks.

As a side note, how can I make it just rotate full circle? I tried passing in 360 but its not doing it??

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can always CGAffineTransformConcat your rotation with a scaling transformation, made with CGAffineTransformMakeScale.

If you're interested in another button pressed effect, I needed something cool, too, and settled on a "throb" animation as follows:

```
BOOL keepThrobbing = NO;

-(void)buttonThrob:(CGFloat)inset {

    UIViewAnimationOptions opts = UIViewAnimationOptionBeginFromCurrentState|UIViewAnimationOptionAllowUserInteraction;

    [UIView animateWithDuration:0.2 delay:0.0 options:opts animations:^{
        self.button.frame = CGRectInset(self.button.frame, inset, inset);
    } completion:^(BOOL finished) {
        [UIView animateWithDuration:0.2 delay:0.0 options:opts animations:^{
            self.button.frame = CGRectInset(self.button.frame, -inset, -inset);
        } completion:^(BOOL finished) {
            if (finished && keepThrobbing) {
                [self buttonThrob:inset];
            }
        }];
    }];
}
```

Call it like this:

```
keepThrobbing = YES;
[self buttonThrob:10.0];  // expand/shrink by 10px in x and y
```

Answer (score 0):

Use CGAffineTransformMakeScale to change the scale.

CustomimageView.transform = CGAffineTransformMakeScale(1.5,1.5);

Answer (score 0):

You can combine two affine transforms with CGAffineTransformConcat:

```
[customimageView setTransform:CGAffineTransformConcat(CGAffineTransformMakeScale(1.5, 1.5), CGAffineTransformMakeRotation(angle))];
```

Comment: thanks for noticing my duplicate post, i deleted it.  not sure how that happened.  i intended a minor edit.