# Button Rotation Animation in swift to make a similar Animation

Tags: ios, xcode, swift, animation, rotation

Rotate a button to make a similar animation when clicked?

[image]
<sub>(source: [cloudfront.net](https://d13yacurqjgara.cloudfront.net/users/28519/screenshots/1985883/gif-dribbble2.gif))</sub>

Comment: The animation is the + and the x animation like when someone click on the + it rotates to a x

Comment: What is your question exactly ?

Comment: You could just do a rotation animation - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5725099/how-to-use-cgaffinetransformmakerotation

Answer (score 35, accepted):

**Swift 3**:

```
UIView.animate(withDuration: 0.25, animations: {
    myButton.transform = CGAffineTransform(rotationAngle: CGFloat.pi)
})
```

More information on rotation in Swift:
[Swift: How can you rotate text for UIButton and UILabel?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28717634/swift-how-can-you-rotate-text-for-uibutton-and-uilabel)

Comment: awesome! how can i add a duration to it?

Comment: I made an edit. Sorry if I'm missing syntax, I'm on mobile.

Comment: UIView.animateWithDuration(0.2, animations: {
   myButton.transform = CGAffineTransformMakeRotation(CGFloat(M_PI_4))
})

Comment: @dorian, thanks I changed it.

Comment: Can't answer or edit, so maybe the author will update: SWIFT 3:

Swift 3

    UIView.animate(withDuration: 0.25, animations: {
        myButton.transform = CGAffineTransform(rotationAngle: CGFloat(M_PI_4))
    }

Comment: for putting back just use 'myButton.transform = .identity'

Answer (score 4):

You can use a regular rotation on the button:

```
[myButton setTransform:CGAffineTransformMakeRotation(M_PI_4)];
```

that would rotat + a 45degrees and make it an X :)

if you want to animate as well try

```
[UIView animateWithDuration:.5 animations:^{
        myButton.transform = CGAffineTransformMakeRotation(M_PI_4);
    }];
```

Comment: am sorry but is this for swift? i am new to swift and it shows errors

Comment: oh my bad, this was objective-c. Swift way of doing it would be myButton.transform = CGAffineTransformMakeRotation(CGFloat(M_PI_4))